# Using xargs command

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, xargs

Can i use `ls - t | xargs > output.txt` by being outside the directory for example

I want to access 
`/home/123/script/final` directory and then perform the above function. Something like this:

```
ls - t | xargs  /home/123/script/final > output.txt
```

but  getting permission denied error

Comment: Welcome to the U&L SE. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with `ls` and `xargs`? Do you simply want to list the files inside the `/home/123/script/final` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the commands you execute actually do?

You want to list the files of that specific directory, so you need to give that as a parameter to `ls`, not to `xargs`.

```
ls -t /home/123/script/final | xargs > output.txt
```

Comment: Hi panki the above command is not working still show  no such file or directory but i do have the final folder

Comment: The directory must exist for `ls` to be able to list its contents, obviously. Also, you need the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

No `xargs` necessary - redirect `ls` output immediately to the destination. If you want all file names in one line, try the `--format=across` option - if available.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access */home/123/script/final* directory and then perform the above function. Something like this:
>   `ls - t | xargs  /home/123/script/final > output.txt`
>   but getting permission denied error

There are a few problems:

1. You need to have the right to access to that home directory.
2. The *ls* command is `ls -lt` and not `ls - t`